# Truncate SQL varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a column of `varchar(3000)`. I want to reduce that to 400 characters.

When I execute this query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[App]
ALTER COLUMN SpecialInstructions VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

How do I set where previous data in that column would just be cut off? I'm using a development database, so it wouldn't matter if I was losing information. Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
update [dbo].[App]
set  SpecialInstructions = left(SpecialInstructions, 400)
```

You can optionally add a `WHERE` clause to make sure only too long values are shortened:

```
where len(SpecialInstructions) > 400
```

This is to reduce the number of rows updated. Keeps transaction smaller, incl write-sets.

Comment: `WHERE LEN(SpecialInstructions) > 400` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx

Comment: @lad2025, `LEN` does not count trailing spaces.  Use `DATALEGNTH` instead here.